# Modify amdgpu script

Tags: gpu, vulkan

I am new to installing drivers in Kubuntu.
After some trail and error and force install reached this point

```
dan@dan-dan-pc:~/Downloads/amdgpu-pro-19.10-785425-ubuntu-18.04$ sudo apt-get install -f ./amdgpu-core_19.10-785425_all.deb 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
Note, selecting 'amdgpu-core' instead of './amdgpu-core_19.10-785425_all.deb'
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  fonts-font-awesome fonts-liberation2 freerdp2-x11 libabw-0.1-1 libadplug-2.2.1-0v5 libaudiofile1 libbinio1v5 libboost-date-time1.67.0 libboost-filesystem1.67.0 libboost-iostreams1.67.0 libboost-locale1.67.0 libboost-system1.67.0 libboost-thread1.67.0 libcdio-cdda2
  libcdio-paranoia2 libcdr-0.1-1 libclucene-contribs1v5 libclucene-core1v5 libcmis-0.5-5v5 libcolamd2 libe-book-0.1-1 libebur128-1 libeot0 libepubgen-0.1-1 libetonyek-0.1-1 libexttextcat-2.0-0 libexttextcat-data libfluidsynth1 libfreecell-solver0 libfreehand-0.1-1
  libfreerdp-client2-2 libfreerdp2-2 libgrantlee-textdocument5 libharfbuzz-icu0 libid3tag0 libjs-sphinxdoc libkf5plotting5 libkf5torrent6 libkf5webkit5 libkgantt2 libkgantt2-l10n libkolabxml1v5 libktorrent-l10n liblangtag-common liblangtag1 libmhash2 libmikmod3 libmms0
  libmodplug1 libmpdclient2 libmspub-0.1-1 libmwaw-0.3-3 libmythes-1.2-0 libodfgen-0.1-1 libopenal-data libopenal1 liborcus-0.14-0 libpagemaker-0.0-0 libphonenumber7 libprotobuf17 libqgpgme7 libqt5networkauth5 libraptor2-0 librasqal3 librdf0 librevenge-0.0-0
  libsdl2-2.0-0 libsidplayfp4 libsuitesparseconfig5 libvisio-0.1-1 libvncclient1 libwildmidi2 libwinpr2-2 libwpd-0.10-10 libwpg-0.3-3 libwps-0.4-4 libxerces-c3.2 libxmlsec1 libxmlsec1-nss libyajl2 libzzip-0-13 lp-solve mariadb-client-core-10.3 mariadb-common
  mariadb-server-core-10.3 paperkey qtgstreamer-plugins-qt5 timgm6mb-soundfont
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  amdgpu-core
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 168 not upgraded.
46 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 12,3 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 /home/dan/Downloads/amdgpu-pro-19.10-785425-ubuntu-18.04/amdgpu-core_19.10-785425_all.deb amdgpu-core all 19.10-785425 [2.416 B]
(Reading database ... 165481 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../amdgpu-core_19.10-785425_all.deb ...
ERROR: This package can only be installed on Ubuntu 18.04.
dpkg: error processing archive /home/dan/Downloads/amdgpu-pro-19.10-785425-ubuntu-18.04/amdgpu-core_19.10-785425_all.deb (--unpack):
 new amdgpu-core package pre-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /home/dan/Downloads/amdgpu-pro-19.10-785425-ubuntu-18.04/amdgpu-core_19.10-785425_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

After much search I think we did it:

```
dan@dan-dan-pc:~/Downloads/amdgpu-pro-19.10-785425-ubuntu-18.04$ sudo lshw -c video
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Hawaii PRO [Radeon R9 290/390]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 80
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=radeon latency=0
       resources: irq:41 memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d07fffff ioport:e000(size=256) memory:fea00000-fea3ffff memory:c0000-dffff
```

Not working, I am switching to Kubuntu 18.04(clean install) maybe that works.

Driver installed but got black screen after reboot. Now i am in safe mode and making all the updates. I hope this will make it work again if not. Time to change distro completely.

Moved to manjaro where everything is in a aur manager called bauh.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Regarding:

```
function os_release() {
[[ -r  /etc/os-release ]] && . /etc/os-release

case "$ID" in
ubuntu|linuxmint|debian)
    :
    ;;
*)
    echo "Unsupported OS" | stderr
    exit 1
    ;;
esac
}
```

Open a terminal and do

```
 more /etc/os-release
```

and remember what it says, edit this file and add what you found (assuming `kubuntu`) like so:

```
kubuntu|ubuntu|linuxmint|debian)
```

Regarding

```
#VERSIONLIST_PACKAGE=amdgpu-pro-pin
```

remove the `#`.

Then save the script and execute it. Mind that there is no guarantee it will work and you might end up with a non-bootable system. Prepare a live usb and find out what to do to remove packages installed regarding video card driver and you can reset from the live session ;)

---

edit Your release shows ....

```
 ID=ubuntu
```

The ID is what is asked for in the script ($ID) so that seems fine to me since `ubuntu` is in the list of accepted releases.

---

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
/tmp/apt-dpkg-install-mDmBng/044-amdgpu-core_19.10-785425_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

is too vague for me. Are you omitting lines? I'd expect more than these 3.

2 options:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

to reconfigure the dpkg database. That might fix the notice.

```
cd /tmp/
sudo apt-get install -f apt-dpkg-install-mDmBng/044-amdgpu-core_19.10-785425_all.deb
```

can be used to force installation. If the .deb is still in /tmp/ that is.

I would not use this script. Download the deb and install that. It is likely to throw more information at you regarding issues it encounters.

Comment: Thanks for the help with this. really appreciate it @Rinzwind